# System.out.printf format

Tags: java

I have written down the following code:

```
public class FractionOfDay {

    public static double fractionOfDay(double h, double m, int s, char a ) {
        double y = -1;
        if (a == 'P' && h == 12) {
            double x = (h * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
             y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'P' && h != 12) {
            double x = ( (h + 12) * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'A' && h == 12) {
            double x = (m * 60) + (s);
            y = x / 86400;
        } else if (a == 'A' && h != 12) {
            double x = ( (h) * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + (s);
            y = x / 86400;
        }
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fractionOfDay(12, 0, 0, 'P'));
    }
}
```

It prints out the fraction of day which has passed from 12 AM .
How can I make it print such a table using `printf`?[image]

Comment: try with "\t" -> tab.

Comment: Have you tried [reading about printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), and following that documentation's link to the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) class?

Comment: @dazito Hi, what do you mean \t ? How can I use that>

Comment: `\t` will tab your text. You can try it like this: `System.out.println("Text \t this is tabbed");` but I'm not sure if this is flexible enough for your needs.

Comment: @VGR Hi, of course I have. However, I just don't understand how it is going to understand to go by one hour increments because in my code, the person has to manually enter the desired value. Also the code is not very well written. It has 4 if statements. Two of which are only for two single scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.format("%tl:%tM %tp %10.4f%n", c, c, c, 
    fractionOfDay(
      c.get(Calendar.HOUR),
      c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
      c.get(Calendar.SECOND),
     (Calendar.AM == c.get(Calendar.AM_PM)) ? 'A' : 'P'));
}
```